# moment().isValid returns true when the input is in integers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

Code:

```
  let modifiedValue = attribute_value;
  let isISOFormat = moment(new Date(attribute_value), moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid();
  if (isISOFormat) {
    modifiedValue = formatDateShortCustom(moment(attribute_value).toDate());
  }
  return modifiedValue;
};
```

In the code above, the attribute value can have

1. `2021-09-29T18:30:00.000Z`
2. `080921`

I want to make sure that when the attribute_value is in (1) format the code
`modifiedValue = formatDateShortCustom(moment(attribute_value).toDate());`
should execute.

However, this numerical string is also causing the `isISOFormat` as `true` hence navigating the `formatDateShortCustom` method, which I don't want?

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: An integer is a valid timestamp since it can represent seconds elapsed since the start of the Unix epoch. If you don't want to allow for numerical string, check it with regex, i.e. `^\d+$`

Comment: `new Date(080921)` outputs `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:01:20 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)` (in my central European console at least :). You are passing that to Moment. Of course Moment says it's a valid date, there's no weirdness here.

Comment: `moment(new Date(attribute_value), moment.ISO_8601, true)` doesn't make any sense. `new Date(attribute_value)` returns a Date object, so providing a parse format is redundant, there's nothing to parse (it's done within `new Date(...)`). Same with the strict parameter, it doesn't to anything. If you want to test that *attribute_value* is ISO 8601 format, then do that explicitly, don't try to infer whether it conforms based on what the built–in parser does with it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest wrapping this in a function `isISOFormat()` and using this to decide whether your input is an ISO 8601 date string.

I'd also suggest passing the input directly to the moment() constructor, rather than creating a Date first:

```js
let attribute_values = ['2021-09-28T11:45:00Z', new Date().toISOString(), 20, null, '28/09/2021', 'is this a date?'];

function testIsISOFormat() {
    for(let attribute_value of attribute_values) {
        console.log(`isISOFormat(${attribute_value}):`, isISOFormat(attribute_value));
    }
}

function isISOFormat(input) {
    return moment(input, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid();
}

console.log('Testing isISOFormat:');
testIsISOFormat()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`moment.ISO_8601` is `undefined` below version `2.7.0`.

That's why `moment` attempts to parse the value regardless of your setting the strict parsing option.
`moment` checks if the string matches [*known ISO 8601 formats*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).

I recommend passing the format as the second argument explicitly.

```js
console.log(moment('2021-09-29T18:30:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ', true).isValid());

console.log(moment('080921', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ', true).isValid());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The moment.js docs do allow you to specify moment.ISO_8601 as of moment 2.7.0+: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/, e.g. moment("2010-01-01T05:06:07", moment.ISO_8601);

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. OP is likely to be using a version earlier than `2.7.0` where it's `undefined`. The behavior isn't reproducible in 2.7.0 and later versions where `moment.ISO_8601` is defined.

Comment: The reason is that in the expression that assigns a value to *isISOFormat*, i.e. `moment(new Date(attribute_value), moment.ISO_8601, true)`, *moment.js* doesn't parse the value at all, it's parsed by the built–in parser and that result (a Date instance) is then passed to *moment.js*.